# Common Mode Choke Usage

Tags: common-mode-choke

I am using a `ACM70V-701-2PL-TL00` [Datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/en/system/files?file=dam/doc/product/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/datasheets/cmf_automotive_power_acm70v_en.pdf) to attempt to filter out A/C ripple in an in-vehicle audio device. I've run the input 12v through one channel of the choke and I attached the other channel to the same ground pour on both ends.

This is not correct, is it? I assume that I should instead split the ground into two polygons with the choke bridging them, correct?

Right now, the choke is not effective, so I am trying to run through what I've done incorrectly.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Show your circuit please.

Comment: That won't filter ripple in the DC input, only common mode noise.

Comment: @KevinWhite - RIght, I'm trying to filter AC ripple, not DC. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your L1 has become a transformer, with a short circuit on the secondary (pins 2 and 3). And as you stated, the secondary is grounded.

Therefore the primary impedance (pins 1 and 4) is a very low impedance, and not functioning as an effective filter.

I don't know if you are using the vehicle chassis as ground to carry return current to the battery.

If you simply want to use the choke as a single inductor (not common mode), then disconnect pins 2 and 3. This can effectively reduce ripple.

For the inductor L1 to act as a common mode choke, the return current to the battery must flow through the choke pins 2 and 3. This can filter common mode noise.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that was the answer -- I'll rewire the ground in two different networks that are unified through pins 2 & 3! Ground goes to a junction that is directly tied to the chassis, yes.